# R - How to find common logical values in two vectors

Tags: r, vector, intersect

1)I need to intersect two vectors and return a vector with the same and with the intersected values.

intersect() does not return a vector with the same size.

2) Also why does this return `c(TRUE TRUE TRUE)` and not `c(FALSE TRUE TRUE)` ?

```
set1 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
set2 = c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)

testset = set1 %in% set2

> print(testset)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I got as result `TRUE TRUE TRUE` and I need `FALSE FALSE TRUE`.

Comment: `%in%` checks "line by line" hence the `TRUE TRUE TRUE` result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do the intersection, you need to use the `&` operator, as follows:

```
testset = set1 & set2
```

This will give you the following result: `FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

`A %in% B` checks for every element in `A` if that element is in `B`. The results always has the same length as `length(A)`. Try e.g.

```
1:3 %in% 1:9
1:9 %in% 1:3
```

I think what you want is this:

```
set1 == set2
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want: why is it F, F,T?

Comment: Sorry, i just realized i need FALSE  FALSE  TRUE. As an "and"(&&) between two vectors.